# R and dplyr: using value of specific group constituent as output of summarise

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summary

I have data that looks something like this:

```
df = data.frame("itm" = c(1,2,1,2,1,2), 
"month" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
"value" = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3,0.2,0.1))

>df
    itm month value
1   1     1   0.6
2   2     1   0.5
3   1     2   0.4
4   2     2   0.3
5   1     3   0.2
6   2     3   0.1
```

I am using dplyr to group the data by month, then summarize to find the average of value by month.

```
> dfg = group_by(df, month)
> dfs = summarize(dfg, avg=mean(value))
> dfs
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  month  avg
1     1 0.55
2     2 0.35
3     3 0.15
```

Everything works as expected up to this point. But I would also like to have a column in dfs which has the "value" of item 2 from the given month.

I thought something like this might work:

```
> dfs$itm2 = filter(dfg, itm==2)
```

but I get:

```
> dfs
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  month  avg     itm2
1     1 0.55 <dbl[3]>
2     2 0.35 <dbl[3]>
3     3 0.15 <dbl[3]>
```

Clearly, I don't know what I'm doing. I suspect that using the "dfs$itm2 =" is a problem.

By the way, I would be quite happy if I could create the "itm2" column with the original summarize command. In principle, I know that I can define a function to select the "itm==2" entry from each group and include that function in the summarise call... in practice I've had no luck.

Apologies if this is a redundant question - I've made an effort to find a similar question, but have not been successful. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
dfg %>% 
    summarise(ave= mean(value), itm2= value[itm==2])
#   month  ave itm2
#1     1 0.55  0.5
#2     2 0.35  0.3
#3     3 0.15  0.1
```

The output of `filter` is a `data.frame` with 3 columns

```
 filter(dfg, itm==2)
 # itm month value
 #1   2     1   0.5
 #2   2     2   0.3
 #3   2     3   0.1
```

So, basically the code in the post was assigning `data.frame/tbl_df` to a column in a `data.frame`.

I guess, you need to select the `value` column and then  assign it to `dfs$itm2`

```
 dfs$itm2 <- filter(dfg, itm==2) %>%
                                .$value
```

Comment: That looks right - I'll try it when I get back to my machine. Thanks for the fast response, akrun!

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks, again

Comment: @msteen Thanks for testing the code and giving the feedback.